# With multiple notifications second notification showing in collapse mode Android

Tags: android, notifications

I'm showing multiple notifications in my android application.

When there is single notification it is showing correctly.

[image]

But when I generate second notification, second notification showing in collapse by default.

[image]

If I manually expand second notification it is showing as:

[image]

I want to show a notifications in expanded mode by default.

Here is my code:

```
int num = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, num  /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        bigTextStyle.bigText(messageBody);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.corco)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setStyle(bigTextStyle)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(num  /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Am i missing something? or doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it. I was not setting any ContentTitle and ContentText for collapse notification.

Here is my updated code:

```
int num = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, num  /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        bigTextStyle.bigText(messageBody);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.corco)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setStyle(bigTextStyle)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(num  /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```